# How do I pick the right Chansey egg?

Tags: pokemon-typing-adventure

In Learn with Pokémon: Typing Adventure, the 7 stage requires you to pick between two eggs (A or B) thrown out by a Chansey. If you pick the right one, a Pokémon appears and you move on to the next round, if you pick the wrong one, it explodes and the stage ends.

How do I determine which egg to pick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a total of 7 rounds to this stage, and Chansey's behavior is different with each round:

1. Pick the egg Chansey jumps up behind.
2. Pick the egg Chansey walks up to.
3. Pick the shaking egg.
4. Pick the faster-shaking egg.
5. Pick the first egg to be thrown out.
6. Pick the egg that casts a shadow.
7. The game will randomly select from one of the above clues; use the appropriate strategy.

Comment: You should probably add a big spoiler alert in front of your answer.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma: We're talking about a (bonus) stage in a typing game, and the game itself directly tells you that there is a strategy. The question directly asks for that strategy, so spoilers of this level (if it can even be *considered* a spoiler) should very much be expected from the title alone.